# Opening Encryption Key Works in Powershell Not in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, cng

I am opening an encryption key stored in an HSM. I have the HSM's client library installed on my machine. If I run the following Windows Powershell snippet:

```
##Open an existing Key
$keyName = 'foo'
$providername = 'SafeNetProtectApp Key Storage Provider'
$provider = New-Object 'System.Security.Cryptography.CngProvider' -ArgumentList $providername
$key = [System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey]::Open($keyName, $provider)
```

It works.

If I attempt to compile the following C# snippet:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace SaveSecret
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(">>> Starting application <<<");

            string keyName = "foo";
            string providerName = "SafeNetProtectApp Key Storage Provider";
            CngProvider provider = new CngProvider(providerName);
            CngKey key = null;
            key = CngKey.Open(keyName, provider);

            System.Console.Write("[Hit Enter to Continue]");
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
  HResult=0x8009001E
  Message=Provider DLL could not be found.

  Source=System.Core
  StackTrace:
   at System.Security.Cryptography.NCryptNative.OpenStorageProvider(String providerName)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Open(String keyName, CngProvider provider, CngKeyOpenOptions openOptions)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Open(String keyName, CngProvider provider)
```

I'm confused why I can open the key using the same libraries in Powershell without an issue. On the same machine, if I attempt the action in C#, I get an exception. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Additional facts...

- Project doesn't target .NET Core
- Compiling C# Console App in Visual Studio 2017 Shell

Comment: where do you get this provider: SafeNetProtectApp Key Storage Provider

Comment: The key store has a CNG provider that you install.

Comment: Are you compiling it in visual studio? Looks like you need to add reference to the DLL for that provider.

Comment: I am. Compiling in VS 2017 shell. So, I thought the same thing. Question, why don’t I need to reference a provider DLL in Posh but I do w/C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project I wrote was targeting the wrong processor architecture. The provider library was 64-bit, but my project was targeting 32-bit. I changed my project to target a 64-bit executable, and it worked.

[image]

Thanks for the help all!

Comment: I got an error about "Unknown error "-1073741823"." and couldn't figure out what was wrong until I found your answer. Thank you :)